# If q ranges over all primes is $q^2 + 3q + 3$ prime infinitely often?

Tags: number-theory

This arose trying to solve a diophantine equation.

Comment: It is not known whether $n^2+3n+3$ is prime infinitely often as $n$ ranges over the integers.

Comment: Am I the only one who sees that $q = 3$ is an easy example of when $q^2 + 3q + 3$ is composite (21, a multiple of 3)?

Comment: @rgettman, I doubt it. But that doesn't answer the question.